# How do I fix this build error > A failure occurred while execurnal.tasks > Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Other errors I got are  `AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.`, `AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.`, `AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I've followed flutter sign configs at edtail. I'm thinking it must be gradle errors.

And here is my `gradle.properties`

```
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
    android.useAndroidX=true
    android.enableJetifier=true
    android.enableR8=true
```

Edit Heres is my `app/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

My compile sdk is 29
android {
compileSdkVersion 29

```
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.scanpal.merchant"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

    }
```

Sign in configs

```
   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }


}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}
```

Could also be androidX compatibilities

```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post up module gradle.build also

Comment: here is your error: ```AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found``` etc. Probably coming from one of your library? or even your project ?

Comment: I've edited @Wini.

Comment: @esQmo_ kindly elaborate

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27226

Comment: What did you do that arised these errors? There seem to be missing some resource in attr folder